# working on refactoring a react component to remove import/no-cycle

Tags: reactjs

**updated**

I have been troubleshooting this and feel like I'm finally at the root of this issue. I went and separated the two css sheets into **Header.scss
 HeaderProfile.scss** and the warning still occurred.

So it looks like this is what is causing the issue:

```
import/no-cycle
```

**index.jsx**

```
import { HeaderProfile } from './HeaderProfile';

export type Props = {
  home: Link,
  links: Link[],
  mobileOnly?: any,
  profile?: Profile,
};
```

**HeaderProfile**

```
import type { Profile } from './index';

export type Props = {
  profile: Profile,
};
```

After talking to Dave, it looks like the issue is that
I'm importing HeaderProfile into index and then needing profile to be imported back into HeaderProfile. I'm talking to the github repo people on next steps

```
// eslint-disable-next-line import/no-cycle
import { HeaderProfile } from './HeaderProfile';
```

Thanks for any help provided!

Link to the github repo:

https://github.com/ifmeorg/ifme/blob/master/client/app/components/Header

Comment: It's not clear what "This is where the circular logic is coming from" means. There's nothing circular shown here.

Comment: Added in additional information, thanks Dave for the edits and the help.

Comment: I still don't understand. `index.jsx` imports `HeaderProfile`. `HeaderProfile` imports `Avatar`. Nothing circular.

Comment: Hi Dave, 
I have a feeling I'm looking at this incorrectly then.
So the other part that could be causing this is that on both
**index.jsx** and **ProfileHeader** are importing css from a scss file.
So it looks like I need to figure out how to get those two separated

Thanks for your help!

Comment: A circular dependency requires a *cyclical dependency*, e.g., two files that mutually import each other. It's irrelevant if two files import the same dependency, it's when there's a *circular* dependency that you get... uh... circular dependencies.

Comment: then I'm not understanding what is causing this error. I'll need to process this a bit and try again.

Comment: You have a circular dependency because `HeaderProfile` imports `Profile`, and your `index` (which exports `Profile`) imports `HeaderProfile`. I'm a ssuming this is flowtype or something; I don't know if you can externalize your types with that, but that's what you'd do in some other systems.

Answer (score 1):

Updated above, but closing this for archiving purposes.
There is a circular importing happening but not as the people in the repo thought. 
Talking to the github repo people on next steps.
The issue is that they are importing in HeaderProfile into index.jsx and then importing Profile back into HeaderProfile